# Upper incomplete Gamma function numerical differences

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I have the following issue. Using Mathematica 11.2 (with Rubi loaded) I find that e.g.

`In[504]:= Gamma[-1/3, 2] // N`

`Out[504]= 0.0353296 + 5.01821*10^-16 I`

The imaginary part is absurd, and the correct approximation is the real part of the output. Indeed, if I look for the result using the Wolfram query, it is the correct one. I am pretty sure that this is a numerical issue since I am getting things like

`In[507]:= Gamma[-10/3, 2] // N`

`Out[507]= 0.00234763 + 0. I`

What can I do to resolve this? Is it something known?

Comment: MMA version 12.1 gives: 0.0353296

Comment: I don't see this with v12.2, try `Gamma[-1/3, 2] // N[#, 20] & // N`

Comment: Again, I get 0.0353296 + 0. I :(

Comment: Use [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html)

Comment: I know I could also use Re[] but that is not the point. The question is about the origin of this issue. Would some extra info help perhaps?

Comment: "The question is about the origin of this issue." - because the internal algorithm involves complex arithmetic, so the result might still have a small imaginary part after numerical evaluation, even if the result is supposed to be real. Use arbitrary precision instead of machine precision if you want a better result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran these on the `WolframCloud` and seemingly the issue is fixed now on `v12.2.0`.

```
$Version
Gamma[-1/3,2]
N@%
Gamma[-1`20/3`20, 2`20]
```

> 12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 16, 2020)
>
> Gamma[-1/3,2]
>
> 0.0353296
>
> 0.035329560217661993

If none of these methods work, I would either do these calculations on the cloud or upgrade your license to the newest version. The issue is one of numerical precision & underlying algorithms.

I will say that the relative magnitude of the complex term is small enough in comparison to the real term to trust in the use of `Chop` as recommended by others.

Comment: Thanks, actually it was resolved already from 12.1

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Gamma[-10/3, 2] // N

(* 0.00234763 + 0. I *)
```

A transformation for `Gamma[a, z]` is

```
repl = Gamma[a_, z_] -> (-z^a + E^z*Gamma[1 + a, z])/(E^z*a);
```

Verifying,

```
Gamma[a, z] == (Gamma[a, z] /. repl) // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Use [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html)

```
Gamma[-10/3, 2] //. 
   Gamma[a_?Negative, z_] -> (-z^a + E^z*Gamma[1 + a, z])/(E^z*a) // 
  Simplify // N

(* 0.00234763 *)
```